# Why did I get a memory error for np.sqrt on a machine with seemingly ample RAM?

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I'm running a simple Python program that takes many hours to create a large (102,000 x 102,000) float32 array (A).  Total memory occupied by the array is ~40GiB, and I'm running this on an Amazon EC2 virtual machine (running Ubuntu) with 130GiB of RAM.  There are no other user processes running, and I can use 'top' to see that, in fact, the program is only using about 56GiB during the array creation phase (don't ask me why it's using even that much), consistently leaving about about 68GiB free, even after allowing for system processes.  So far, so good.

But the near-final line in the program is

```
A = np.sqrt(A)
```

and at this point, the program crashes with a memory error.  I don't understand why this is happening, even allowing for the need for a temporary array of the same size (this should still leave about 28 GiB free).  The only thing I can think of is that np.sqrt() might be internally using float64 for the scratch space.  Is there any other possible explanation?

My only workaround right now is to compute the square root element-by-element in for loops.

Comment: try `np.sqrt(A, dtype=np.float32)`.

Comment: `np.sqrt(A, out=A)` should fix this particular MemoryError, but we can't say what's causing you to blow your RAM without seeing pretty much your whole program.

Comment: I think @user2357112 solution should definitely work (and should definitely be preferred), however, I'd be curious if providing the `dtype=np.float32` argument to `np.sqrt` would solve your problem. Testing it out, it seems to require a smaller amount of memory. There is a lot of arcana involved with ufuncs...